# Data binding across several windows with WPF / Entity Framework? Pass context around or not?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, entity-framework-4

Most WPF/EF tutorials only cover databinding in one window. However, in reality data gets displayed across many windows. You often display a record in the first window and dig deeper in related details in the next windows.

So, this also is the case in my scenario. Here you can see my data structure and the ui. Actually I am not dealing with Customers and Invoices, but the structure is the same. (My concrete questions are at the very end.)

[image: db design and ui mockup]

In the InvoicesWindow I can select an Invoice and press "Show Invoice". That opens a CustomerWindow displaying Customer details and his invoices. The right invoice is pre-selected. To each Invoice displayed in the CustomerWindow I can add Items or edit them. This is done in a seperated window called "ItemWindow". Editing the DataGrids is not an option. They are set to ReadOnly.

Here is the code of the wpf-window classes (I only have done displaying data yet, not saving):

**Invoices Window:**

```
public partial class InvoicesWindow : Window 
{ 
    private MyEntities context = new MyEntities();

    public InvoicesWindow () 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        CollectionViewSource invoicesViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("invoicesViewSource");
        invoicesViewSource.Source = context.Invoices;
    }

    private void ShowInvoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        Invoice selectedInvoice = (Invoice)InvoicesDataGrid.SelectedItem; 
        var customerWindow = new CustomerWindow(selectedInvoice);
        customerWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Customer Window:**

```
public partial class CustomerWindow : Window 
{ 
    private MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
    private Invoice selectedInvoice;

    public CustomerWindow() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    public CustomerWindow (Invoice selectedInvoice) 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        this.selectedInvoice = selectedInvoice;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        //Set the data 
        CollectionViewSource customerViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("customerViewSource ");
        customerViewSource.Source = context.Customers.Where(p => p.id == selectedInvoice.Customer.id);

        //Select the right invoice
        CollectionViewSource customerInvoicesViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("customerInvoicesViewSource ");
        customerInvoicesViewSource.Items.MoveCurrentTo(((ObjectSet<Invoice>)customerInvoicesViewSource.Source).Where(p => p.id == selectedInvoice.id).SingleOrDefault());
    }

    private void EditItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        Item selectedItem = (Item)ItemsDataGrid.SelectedItem; 
        var itemWindow = new ItemWindow((IQueryable<Customer>)(customerViewSource.Source),selectedInvoice,selectedItem);
        itemWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Item window:**

```
public partial class ItemWindow : Window 
{ 

    private Invoice _selectedInvoice;
    private Invoice _selectedItem;
    private IQueryable<Customer> _customers;

    public ItemWindo() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    public ItemWindow(IQueryable<Customer> customers, Invoice selectedInvoice, Item selectedItem) 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        this._customers = customers;
        this._selectedInvoice = selectedInvoice;
        this._selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        //Set the data 
        CollectionViewSource customerViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("customerViewSource");
        invoicesViewSource.Source = _customers;

        //Select the right invoice
        CollectionViewSource customerInvoicesViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("customerInvoicesViewSource ");
        customerInvoicesViewSource.Items.MoveCurrentTo(_selectedInvoice);

        //Select the right item
        CollectionViewSource customerInvoicesItemsViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("customerInvoicesItems");
        customerInvoicesItems.Items.MoveCurrentTo(_selectedItem);
    }

}
```

I wrote the code out of my mind. So, maybe some casts are missing and some methods are mis-spelled. I hope I got the right type with "ObjectSet", it also could be "ObjectCollection" or something like that.

The XAML was created widely with assistance of VS2010 like in this video: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/data/ff806174.aspx

**So, finally my questions ;)**

- Is the design of binding I applied correct?

  - In CustomerWindow I create a new context.
  - Between CustomerWindow and ItemWindow I just pass the data of the same context and select the current item manually.
  - In CustomerWindow I use a ObjectSet (or ObjectCollection, I'm not sure about the type anymore) with a single entry as Source for the customersCollectionViewSource. This works fine. However, there is no need for a collection, because I only edit a single Customer. I did not manage to set a single Customer as Source. I didn't know how to adjust the view source which was generated by VS2010.
- I haven't done saving yet. But I think I am going to run into problems due to my design between CustomerWindow and ItemWindow. Maybe you can give me some advice here.

  - When the "Apply"-Button in ItemWindow gets pressed, the Item data should be updated in DB. But not the Customer- and Invoices-related data in the CustomerWindow underneath.
  - The DataGrid of Items in CustomerWindow should get updated, when closing the ItemWindow. But not the rest of the fields in the CustomerWindow, since here could have been data changed before opening the ItemWindow.
  - The only solution for me to overcome that "synchronisation problem": The User is forced to press "Apply" in the CustomerWindow before he can press the "New Item" or "Edit Item", if there have been any changes. (Kinda like the "window resolution control" of windows 7 when working with two monitors) But this is not too user friendly.

Comment: What did you use to create the mockups?

Comment: @Benjamin I used Google Drive > Drawing for this fast one. Google Drive has many advantages: It's simple, fast, you can collaborate, discuss or publish it to the web. For finer Mockups for Windows Applications I use Microsoft Visio which has templates for many windows controls.

Comment: Little update to how I implemented it now: So far, I find nothing strange anymore to pass the context around and to manipulate the CurrentItem in the View. I now pass it also between Invoices and Customer window. I removed the "Apply"-Button from the ItemWindow. The changes will only get stored in DB when clicking Apply or OK in the CustomerWindows. When "Cancel" gets pressed in the ItemWindow I do following to restore the data: `context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, selectedItem);`

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner design would be to use the MVVM design pattern.

Inject the view model into the window's context and bind the view model to either a collection of entities or a single entity, bind in the xaml to properties in the view model(s) and use commands implemented in the view model for actions e.g. add new, delete.

The windows shouldn't be aware of the context.

If you have a list view model + window and a details window (preferably with a view model), then the list view model should pass the selected item to the details view model (or window) as the context.

If the windows are not open at the same time or do not have related objects, then their views models should not share a database context, otherwise, in order for the changes to be reflected easily between the windows, they will have to share the database context.